# (Javascript) i want to reduce every duplicate values in 2 Dimensional Array but i don't know how

Tags: javascript, arrays

my English is not good but i really need your help.

I want to reduce all same values in this 2 Dimensional Array but it doesn't work.

```
let edge = [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4],[0,2,4]];   

 function removeDup(edge) {
      for (let i = 0; i < edge.length; i++) {
        if (edge.some((item) => item > 1)) {
          edge.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      return edge;
    }
```

i want to change array like this.

```
 [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4],[0,2,4]]

to

[[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4]]
```

Comment: Define 'duplicate'. Is, for example `[0,2,4]` a duplicate of `[2,0,4]`?

Comment: can you explain your goal specifically? please write your expected output

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular
 ,@ishlahmuzakki i edited post! thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the word **reduce** in *I want to reduce all duplicate values* ....?

Comment: @PeterKA i'm sorry that means same elements. google translation makes everyone confused.

Comment: Construct an object where the key is the inner array & the value is how many times the inner array is found in `edge`. Then, iterate over the object to filter only those where the value is 1. Will try to submit an updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the the `filter()` array method with the `every()` array method as shown below:

```js
let edge = [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4],[0,2,4]];   

function removeDup(edge) {
    return edge.filter(
        (cur,i) => edge.slice(0,i).every(
            prev => !prev.every(elm => cur.includes(elm))
        )
    );
}

console.log( removeDup(edge) );
//output: [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4]]
```

If your goal is to remove all elements that are repeated, you would need to use the whole array, `edge`, instead of `edge.slice(0,i)` and, avoid comparing an element with itself - `i !== j` - as shown below:

```js
let edge = [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4],[0,2,4]];   

function removeDup(edge) {
    return edge.filter(
        (cur,i) => edge.every(
            (prev,j) => !prev.every(elm => i !== j && cur.includes(elm))
        )
    );
}

console.log( removeDup(edge) );
//output: [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4]]
```

Another approach would be:

1. To convert each element array to a single value by first sorting the elements and joining them
2. Then use `filter()` to only return the element array that return a frequency of 1
3. Use an inner `filter()` to count how many times each converted element appears in the array.
4. `[...cur]` ensures original elements are not sorted, since arrays are passed by reference.

```js
let edge = [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4],[0,2,4]];   

function removeDup(edge) {
    const nedge = edge.map(cur => [...cur].sort().join(''));
    return edge.filter(
        cur => nedge.filter(
            n => n === [...cur].sort().join('')
        ).length === 1 
    );
}

console.log( removeDup(edge) );
//output: [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired result:

Copying from the question:

```
[[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4],[0,2,4]]
```

to

```
[[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4]]
```

*Note*: The desired target array has no `[0, 2, 4]`.

**Code Sample**

```
const removeDupes = arr => (
  Object.entries(
    arr.reduce(
      (fin, itm) =>
        ({...fin, [itm]: (fin[itm] || 0) + 1})
      ,{}
    )
  ).filter(
    ([k ,v]) => v === 1
  ).map(x => x[0])
);
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate over the array using `.reduce` to generate an object
- The key of the resulting object will be each inner array (such as `[0, 1, 4]`
- The value will be a count (number of times the inner array is found in `edge`)
- Once the object is generated, iterate over its `entries` to filter only those which have a count of exactly 1
- Now, use `.map` to pull only the keys of the object.

**Code Snippet**

```js
let edge = [[0,1,4],[1,2,4],[0,2,4],[2,3,4],[3,0,4],[0,2,4]];

const removeDupes = arr => (
  Object.entries(
    arr.reduce(
      (fin, itm) =>
        ({...fin, [itm]: (fin[itm] || 0) + 1})
      ,{}
    )
  ).filter(
    ([k ,v]) => v === 1
  ).map(x => x[0])
);

console.log(removeDupes(edge));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution by using the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
let edge = [
  [0, 1, 4],
  [1, 2, 4],
  [0, 2, 4],
  [2, 3, 4],
  [3, 0, 4],
  [0, 2, 4],
];

function removeDuplicate(edge) {
  return edge.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    !acc.some((elm) => elm.every((e, i) => cur[i] === e)) && acc.push(cur);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(removeDuplicate(edge));
```